# How do I tap to move to the next ViewPager page fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager setup that's been working fine for my app but it only lets me *swipe the screen to move to the next slide*. What I want is to *also be able to move to the next slide by tapping the screen*. Is this possible?

I've been trying to figure this out for a week but I couldn't find the right code to make it work.

Here's what I've done so far:

```js
public class JoyfulHappyfuntime extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_joyful_happyfuntime);
            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        }

        private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
                switch(pos) {

                    case 0: return new BoopTheName();
                    case 1: return new Creed();
                    case 2: return new Waffles();
                    case 3: return new Smilea();
                    case 4: return new Smileb();
                    case 5: return new Smilec();
                    case 6: return new PancakesOne();
                    case 7: return new FirstJoyfulHappyfuntime();
                    case 8: return new Waffles();
                    case 9: return new Smilea();
                    case 10: return new Smileb();
                    case 11: return new Smilec();
      //etc
                    default: return new Continue();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 74;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of those :

- Adding a transparent view ontop where you handle the onClick to change
  the position to the next.
- using a `ViewPagerIndicator` on top to let the user click on the section he wants

[View Pager Tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2450910)

Comment: Hi, thank you. This seems useful, it really does, but i want the app to move to the next slide by touching or tapping any part of the screen without having to interact with tabs.

Comment: Have you tried to register to the fragment on click??

Comment: In the end, i used a couple of views as navigation buttons. it's been working quite well but I haven't tried it on a view that covers the whole screen. I'm sure it'll work, though. thanks.